# numpy setting multidimensional arrays with index arrays containing NaNs

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a problem that has been driving me insane for about a week. I am starting off with a large array of shape (2700, 1000, 3) called A and then have 2 arrays of shape (800, 600), called B and C. A and B are filled with indices that are of interest for the larger array as such

```
A[B[i][j]][C[i][j]].shape
```

is a 1d array of 3 values such as [0, 0, 0] at the indices given by B[i][j] and C[i][j]. Now I want to set this equal to another array of shape (800, 600) called D. This works out if I use the following method:

```
D[:] = A[B, C]
```

However, I am now introducing NaN terms into B and C. This means that A[B][C] returns an error when this is encountered. I cannot simply do the following:

```
B = np.where(np.logical_or(B>0, C>0), B, 0)
```

As that will make the NaN values be replaced by 0s, what I ultimately want is when the indices representing B or C are NaN:

```
D[i][j] = [0, 0, 0]
```

My most recent attempt was implementing something like this:

```
D = np.where(np.logical_or(np.isnan(A), np.isnan(B)), self.pix[A, B], [0,0,0])
```

However the NaN indices are still passing through. Sorry if this post doesnt parse well, I am trying to explain in as well as I can.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve, however it does not work yet:

```
import numpy as np

import numpy as np

coords = np.array([[[3, 4, 2], [2, 1, np.nan]], [[2,3,2],[1, 0, 2]]])
x = np.divide(coords[0], 2)
y = np.divide(coords[1], 2)
a = np.array([1, 1, 1])
a1 = a*1
a2 = a*2
a3 = a*3
a4 = a *4

A =  np.array([[a1, a2, a2, a1], [a2, a3, a3, a4],  [a3, a4, a4, a1],  [a3, a4, a1, a1]])
D =  np.array([[a1, a2, a4], [a1, a3, a2]])

print(np.where(np.isnan(x)))
D = (np.where(x>0, A[x.astype(int), y.astype(int)], [0, 0, 0]))
```

Comment: I cannot even put a `NaN` in an index array, because `NaN` is `float` not integer. Example `a = np.arange(10)` `a[0] = np.nan` raises a `ValueError`.

Comment: Can't you keep the masking information separate? Then you could do something along the lines `D = np.zeros((*B.shape, 3), A.dtype)` `D[mask, :] = A[B[mask], C[mask]]`

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thats because arange(10) initiates the array as dtype=int because you pass it an int, mine is initiated as a float array as it is declared with floats/np.nan

Comment: You are, of course, right. What I mean is that that's not an optimal representation, because as floats are not allowed as indices you'll have to ultimately strip the `NaN`s and convert to int. As this seems unnecessarily cumbersome, why not store the mask separately from the get go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use separate boolean masks for the NaNs in the indexing arrays and then extend the combined mask to 3D with a new axis using [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and use it with `np.where` -

```
B_nanmask = np.isnan(B)
C_nanmask = np.isnan(C)
BC_nanmask = B_nanmask | C_nanmask

# Replace NaNs with zeros to have a *valid* array w/o NaNs
B[B_nanmask] = 0
C[C_nanmask] = 0

out = np.where(BC_nanmask[...,None], 0, A[B.astype(int),C.astype(int)])
```

Alternatively, assign into indexed array -

```
out = A[B.astype(int),C.astype(int)]
out[BC_nanmask] = 0
```

If you don't want to disturb the indexing arrays, we could setup their integer versions separately -

```
B_int = np.where(B_nanmask, 0, B.astype(int))
C_int = np.where(C_nanmask, 0, C.astype(int))
out = np.where(BC_nanmask[...,None], 0, A[B_int, C_int])
```